# Adding More information than a image to an image classifier in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

i am trying to make an image classifier with keras to predict cases of breast câncer, i had some troubles until here because it's not a "simple" classifire, i couldn't do this with the traditional methods with keras. So i am trying to add more information than just a image, like an array [image, age, density]. I am new at this so i dont know if it's possible or how to search for the rigth way to do this, i am trying to do this this way:

```
X = np.array(X) \\ the image

y = np.array(y) \\ an array with 1 or 0 (cancer or not)

z = np.array(z) \\ the density of the breast
```

\ al the arrays correspond to the same case like `X[0]` is the image `y[0]` if this case is cancer or not and `z[0]` the density os this case

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = X.shape[1:],activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation = 'softmax')) 
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


model.fit(X,z,y, epochs = 20) // i actually don't know how to give the information to the model
```

this is the error:

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`

Comment: I would convert to flat array `[pixel1, pixel2, ..., last_pixel, age, density]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fit does not take parameter like that. If you look at the [function definition](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) the first parameter is input, second is target prediction, and the third is batch size.

What you should do is concatenate X and z (and any other info), as they are both input data. e.g.

```
Xz = np.concatenate((X, z[..., np.newaxis]), axis=-1)
```

Note: `z[..., np.newaxis]` takes an array with size `[H, W]` and makes it `[H, W, 1]` so that you can concatenate it with X, which I assume is an RGB image with shape `[H,W,3]`. If it is greyscale, just ignore this and simple use `z`.

Utimately what you want is the input to have dimension [H,W,C] where C is the dimension of all the data, e.g. [red, green, blue, age, density, etc]. It might make more sense in the network design to inject non-image information, like age, in at the final layers of the network (e.g. into Dense(128))

Comment: Thanks for your help, the image is RGB, i had tryied this:

Xz = np.concatenate((X,z[np.newaxis,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]), axis=-1)

But this error appears:

all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1000 and the array at index 1 has size 1