# Concatenating an image to an additional information for keras

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make an image classifier with Keras to predict cases of breast cancer, I had some troubles until here because it's not a "simple" classifier, I couldn't do this with the traditional methods with Keras. So I am trying to add more information than just an image, like an array `[image, age, density]`.

I am new at this, so I don't know if it's possible or how to search for the right way to do this.

I am trying to do this in this way:

```py
X = np.array(X) # the image    
y = np.array(y) # an array with 1 or 0 (cancer or not)    
z = np.array(z) # the density of the breast
```

All the arrays correspond to the same case like `X[0]` is the image `y[0]` if this case is cancer or not and `z[0]` the density of this case.

And than I am trying to concatenate the `X` and `z` like this:

```py
Xz = np.concatenate((X, z[np.newaxis,np.newaxis]), axis=-1)
```

and `Z` with this new axis is this shape in final `(1, 1, 1000, 1)`.
and this error appears:

> all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1000 and the array at index 1 has size 1

I would use this model to train the `Xz` array:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = X.shape[1:],activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation = 'softmax')) 
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(Xz,y, epochs = 10)
```

Comment: You can't use `concatenate` to join a scaler element to an 2d image array.  And I doubt if `keras` could handle such a mix data elements.  But if there is a way, it will found in keras docs, not numpy methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447960/adding-more-information-than-a-image-to-an-image-classifier-in-keras?noredirect=1#comment120970191_68447960

Comment: In this link this guy had told me to do this, but i think i am doing something wrong

Comment: Since you have 3 different inputs in your model I would suggest you not to use a single Sequential model but instead go for Functional API. There is a nice guide here. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: The earlier recommendation was to add new `y` and `z` values to each pixel of `x`, effectively a new "color" channel.  What's the shape of `z`?  Take seriously the dimensions in that answer ( (H,W) => (H,W,1) etc).